# Make the keyboard in my iOS 7 app translucent/transparent

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios7, uikeyboard

I've seen that iOS 7 brings some cool features in terms of design, and I was wondering whether I can make the keyboard transparent, as I've seen in some apps.
If so, how can I do it?

I've done a bit of research but haven't found much about it.

Comment: I believe it is transparent automatically

Comment: if it were, I wouldn't be asking this; in Interface Builder you can only chose from default, light or dark

Comment: For my app, it works automatically.

Comment: It's automatic when built with iOS 7 SDK, but you only see it on supported devices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're working with Xcode 5, the keyboard in iOS 7 ***IS*** transparent by default. You don't have to do anything. In IB/Storyboard, place a `UITextField` onto a ViewController, and turn that ViewController's view green (or some other color). When you click in the `UITextField` and the keyboard comes up, you'll notice that you can see the view's background color through the keyboard.

Comment: This is only true if the app is build on Xcode 5 with a Base SDK of iOS 7. If you build the app on Xcode 4.6.3 and deploy to an iOS 7 device, this won't be the case.

Comment: umm..I'm working with xCode 5 and iOS 7 and I just turned my background purple. I don't see purple through the keyboard. I only see light grey.

Comment: Can someone please shed some light on this topic, I too am having the same problem! i have even created a simple single view based application and successfully able to recreate the problem! the keyboard does not show the colours from the view behind it! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20793866/uikeyboard-not-automatically-translucent-in-ios7 Here is my question

Answer (score 1):

In order for the keyboard to be translucent by default, you will need to build your app on Xcode 5 with your Base SDK set to iOS 7.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an IB file originally created in an earlier Xcode, click on the File Inspector and change the View As property to Xcode 5.