# UIKeyboard not automatically translucent in iOS7

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, xcode5, uikeyboard

I understand that when developing in Xcode 5 with and iOS 7 project, the keyboard that pops up when interacting with a UITextField should be translucent and show through any colors in the background. This is not the case in both my projects. I have a colored & blurred background and I'm hoping for that to transpire through the keyboard; however the keyboard remains the default white/gray.

This is what I have so far as a demo:

```
UIColor *tintColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.21 alpha:0.4];
UIColor *background = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"universe.jpg"] applyBlurWithRadius:19
                                                                                                            tintColor:tintColor
                                                                                                saturationDeltaFactor:1.8
                                                                                                            maskImage:nil]];
self.view.backgroundColor = background;

UITextField *text = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, 200, 300, 60)];
[self.view addSubview:text];
```

I have even tried to set the keyboard appearance type to both UIKeyboardAppearanceDefault and UIKeyboardAppearanceLight

Can someone please guide/tell me on how can I achieve the keyboard translucent effect? Should this be automatic? 
Thanks

**EDIT 1:**

I have the iPad mini, I have the iPad 3rd generation and the iPad 4th generation both with retina displays. 
Running iOS 7.0.2

Comment: did you have created the project in Xcode 5 and with iOS 7.

Comment: Yes, I have shabir! as i said, i simply opened up xcode 5.0.3 and created an ios 7 project obviously with the single based view application and added a simply uitextfield with the background of the view changed to a colourful display hoping for it to show through a translucent keyboard. The keyboard does not do that! pls let me know whats happening and how I can fix the issue! thank you

Comment: What device are you using?

Comment: @LeoNatan Hey thanks for stopping by, please check the updated post, I have added more info.

Comment: I haven't really taken a look at this but I believe if the user has `Increase Contrast` turned on in accessibility the keyboard will not be blurred anyway.  You may not have it turned on so that may not be what your problem is but this is something to keep in mind if you release this app.

Comment: Hey thanks evan. My increased contrast is already set to off though.

Comment: try to opt-out autolayout in inspector.

Comment: I don't understand how unchecking the 'Use autolayout' property in the inspector tab would help make my UIKeyboard translucent buddy. However @thorb I did do as you said and unfortunately it didn't do the magic :(

Comment: because autolayout effects the manual configuration of ui elements. in which method you are adding the textField? should be in viewWillAppear...

Comment: @thorb in the viewDidLoad method, I have cut and paste the code into the viewWillAppear method, and yet again its not product the desired effect, still the plain ole keyboard! grrr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I built a simple app to test to try to find this issue, but I've been unable to replicate it except by setting IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET to a lower version number like 6.0, then running on iOS 6.0.  In all cases, on all iOS 7 devices and simulator, the default keyboard has a translucent blur of the content underneath it.

Perhaps you could share a picture, or a sample project?

[image: Set Xcode to target running on iOS 6.0 simulator]

[image: No translucency to the keyboard]

[image: Set Xcode to target running on iOS 7.0 simulator]

[image: Translucency to the keyboard]

Comment: See now this is awesome. Dude how are you doing this? I have created a new xCode project set the background color to red and cannot get any sort of translucency at all!! Could you upload that xcode project of yours so that I can download it and test on my end

Comment: I've edited my message to show the app running under different versions of iOS.  I basically did exactly what you did.  I created a single view application.   For fun, I used paint code to create a UIView subclass that draws a bunch of scribbles in the view, but I could have just set the background color to red.  I added a UITextField to get the keyboard.

Comment: ok I am getting somewhere, i noticed both of you guys tested on the iPhone, so this time I tried on the iPad but deployed as an iPhone app and the keyboard shows its translucency, however when deploying as an iPad application the keyboard is not translucent.

Could you deploy on an ipad please and share your results? Since it is an iPad app.

Comment: The keyboard is never translucent on the iPad.  The keyboard screen area is so large and blur effect so slow that they never do that.  Even when you run an app that is targeted for the iPhone on the iPad, the keyboard will not be translucent, and Apple has no requirement or suggestion that it should ever be translucent.

Comment: I ran an iPhone app on my iPad application and the keyboard was translucent, remember it just treats the iPad like an iPhone and scales it up. Ah so the iPad keyboard will never be translucent? Is there any documentation on this that confirms this so i can finally put an end to this

Comment: I ran one and it wasn't translucent.  I think the point is that you shouldn't worry about it which one it chooses, and it's not under your control for which one it does choose.

Answer (score 5):

Your code, setup and example worked fine on my xCode.  I tried first only setting the background color to something obvious like red.

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

This showed through the keyboard. Afterwards I tried an image without a blur effect.

```
UIImageView* img = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"images.jpeg"]];
img.frame = self.view.frame;
[self.view addSubview:img];
```

This to showed through, but not as much as the red because the image I used was one similar to a galaxy as you stated, and therefore had a lot of black in it.

Lastly I tried your exact code, using the gaussian blur effect to create a color.

```
UIColor *tintColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.21 alpha:0.4];
UIColor *background = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"images.jpeg"] applyBlurWithRadius:19 tintColor:tintColor saturationDeltaFactor:1.8 maskImage:nil]];
self.view.backgroundColor = background;
```

This to also worked, but it was extreamly hard to notice.  The combined affect of dark colors being blurred once by the gaussian and being blurred again by the keyboard made it almost unnoticeable.  I suggest you try a similar approach to see if you are actually getting a transparent keyboard, because if the code and info you have given are correct, then it seems like you are and maybe can not see it.

Also the keyboard is only slightly transparent, so if you are expecting a full transparency then that is not the case. This slight transparency gets minimized the more uniform the background color is for instance if you had an all black or white background it would be unnoticeable.

Edit: I confirmed that this is not the case on the iPad running iOS7.0.x  I get the standard all grey keyboard, even using standard apps like Safari. It seems that Apple had not optimized the transparency for such large screens and it was causing lag issues. It also seems that this is partially fixed in iOS7.1 and there are more transparent iPad features in iOS7.1, but people are recommending turning them off as they cause the iPad to run slower than normal.

Comment: This is absolutely ridiculous! your explanation was beautiful especially your last paragraph where you explained transparency being minimised. However, I have created a new project in xCode 5.x.x with built for iOS 7 setting the background to red, and screenshotting the keyboard, and then i also screenshot the apple's notepad keyboard which would hover above a white paged background, and compared the photos to frustratingly still see no difference in keyboard colors! I was hoping your answer would have shed some light :(

Comment: @Pavan Seems to be limited to iPhone for now due to speed concerns. May be possible in the iOS7.1 release

Comment: Thank you for the update. Your edit helped you win the bounty. Cheers. But please do tell me your source, and how you are aware that things will look better in the iOS 7.1 release. Some sources would be helpful to help clear my mind.

Answer (score 3):

iOS 7.0.3 reduced much of the translucency in navigation bars, toolbars, and the keyboard.

For navigation bars and toolbars, starting in iOS 7.0.3, you can adjust the `alpha` property of the UIColor set as `barTintColor` if you want it more translucent.

As far as public APIs go, keyboards in iOS 7, however, still have only these options:

```
textField.keyboardAppearance = UIKeyboardAppearanceDefault;  // the default (same as light)
textField.keyboardAppearance = UIKeyboardAppearanceDark;  // dark look (previously UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert)
textField.keyboardAppearance = UIKeyboardAppearanceLight;  // light look
```

So I assume you're not getting the translucency you'd like because you're using iOS 7.0.3 or later.  You can verify this by [downloading an older version of Xcode and running your app in that version's simulator](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?q=xcode).

As far as private APIs, the keyboard background is made up of `UIKBBackdropView` and `UIKBBackgroundView`.  You can [take a look at their extracted header files here](https://github.com/JaviSoto/iOS7-Runtime-Headers/tree/master/Frameworks/UIKit.framework), but you should not modify these if you're submitting to the App Store.  (These modifications are grounds for rejection, and also aren't documented so they could be changed in any iOS update.)

Comment: dude, im running ios 7.0.2 :) so according to your post buddy I should be seeing translucency in my keyboard, and i am not at all seeing that, which is what I stated in my question. The translucency with other UI elements are fine, such as the: navigation bar, uisearchbar etc.
Thanks for taking your time in writing up your post bro. It does not apply to my situation atm.

Comment: Please do have a thorough read of my original question again. Thank you

Comment: You stated you're using Xcode 5.0.3 (which doesn't exist, so I assume you mean Xcode 5.0.2.)  Have you tried my suggestion of building your app on Xcode 5.0?

Comment: aha sorry Aaron, that was a typo. I am using xCode 5.0.2. I am downloading xcode 5.0 as we speak, thanks for the link, I will get back to you in a moment once I've downloaded the file, and running my project on that older version of xcode. Does it have to be through the simulator or can I run the test on my device through the old xcode 5.0?

Comment: I think 5.0 won't build to a 7.0.2 device (but 5.0.1 will).  I'm only 75% sure that's correct, though.

Comment: Hey, so I have downloaded xcode 5.0 and built my project with that and ran it on that verion's iPad simulator and it didnt create the translucent effect, I was also able to successfully build to my iPad device and its doing the same thing buddy. I dont understand why the keyboard wont be translucent! I appreciate your time Aaron. Im willing to try other things too